# focus not working on element even with setTimeout()

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular

iam trying to set focus on an element using jquery as renderer from angular cant be used if the element is outside of the component

But $("#selector").focus() is not working Tried the following

not working

```
setTimeout(() => $(window.parent.document).find("button[tabindex='0']").first().focus(), 400);
```

Tried increasing  the timeout upto 1000 and more in the above code but still not working.

The following surprisingly works

```
  setTimeout(() => $(window.parent.document).find("button[tabindex='0']").first().focus(), 100);
    setTimeout(() => $(window.parent.document).find("button[tabindex='0']").first().focus(), 300);
```

I dont know why the second approach works.I dont really like the second approach.

please suggest 
1.any alternative way of doing the above without using two setTimeouts.
2.better way of setting focus using angular(like using renderer but the element to be focused is outside of the component where iam setting the focus ) instead of jquery

Comment: Could you give us some context ? So that maybe we can find a solution that copes with Angular ?

Comment: yeah i am running two apps each one on different ports ,we  dont have access to the element to be focused(as its in different app) in the  component where i am setting the focus .so i think  renderer is not working.is there any way to do this by using some angular builtins

Comment: I think focus works in Angular's `AfterViewInit` lifecycle hook

Comment: yeah but its working only if two setTimeouts are used as i mentioned earlier.i want to make it work with one even if the timeout is little bit more